# mysql grant privileges without identified by password

Tags: mysql, ddl, user-management

When I run:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on database.* to user@localhost;
```

It returns:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Shouldn't it give an error as I'm not including "identified by 'password'" ?

Please clarify, the user already has a password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the documentation:

> Without `IDENTIFIED BY`, the account password remains unchanged.

Since the account already exists, and has a password, and you don't want to change it, you should indeed **not** specify an `identified by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

5.5 or newer versions of MySQL you should confirm that a command like `grant all privileges on database.* to user@'10.1.1.12;` actual does what you want. I'm seeing it create a user without a password, that is you can login with an empty password.